# Puppeteer on Heroku, memory errors

Tags: heroku, puppeteer

Trying to get Heroku to run some [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) jobs. Locally, it works. It's slow but it works. Monitoring the memory in OS X `Activity Monitor`, it doesn't get above 50MB. But when I deploy this script to Heroku, I'm getting a `Memory quota exceeded` every time, and the memory footprint it much larger.

Looking at the logs, I'm getting the message:

`Process running mem=561M(106.5%)` .
`Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)` .
`Restarting` .
`State changed from up to starting`

Either Activity Monitor is not reporting the memory correctly, or something is going wrong only when running the script on Heroku. I can't imagine why a page scrape of 25 pages would be 561M.

Also since the Puppeteer scripts must be contained in `try/catch`—the memory error is crashing the Dyno and restarting. By the time the Dyno restarts, the browser hangs up. So the `restarting` does little good. Is there a way to catch 'most' errors on Heroku but throw when there is a memory R14 error?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. What I discovered is that if you are not closing the browser you will get immediately an R14 error. What I recommend:

1. Make sure you use a single browser instance and multiple contexts instead of multiple browsers.
2. Make sure you close the contexts after you call pdf
3. If you are processing large pages you need to scale your heroku instance, you don't have a choice. Unfortunately, you need to pay 50$ for 1GB of memory on heroku...

   Some ugly code but it points the fact you context is closed after calling pdf function.

```js
browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext().then((context)=>{
    context.newPage().then((page)=>{
        page.setContent(html).then(()=>{
            page.pdf(options).then((pdf)=>{
                let inputStream = bufferToStream(pdf);
                let outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
                inputStream.pipe(outputStream).on("finish", () => {
                    context.close().then(()=>{
                        resolve();
                    }).catch(reject);
                });
                
            });
        }).catch(reject)
    }).catch(reject)
}).catch(reject);
```